# Colors on a 3D curve not working

Tags: plotting, color, parametric-functions

I'm having troubles applying colors to a simple 3D curve plot.  Here's the code :

```
Color1 = RGBColor[0, 0, 1];
Color2 = RGBColor[1, 0, 0];
Color3 = RGBColor[0, 1, 0];

CouleurLigne[t_] := Blend[{Color1, Color2, Color3},  Rescale[t, {Tmin, Tmax}]]

Tmin = 0;
Tmax = 4 Pi;

ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t], Cos[t], t}, {t, Tmin, Tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1]]}, ColorFunction -> (CouleurLigne[#] &), MaxRecursion -> 7, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

I'm getting the curve with the first color applied to it.  No blending from color1 to color3.  What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Just a note that your `Color1`, `Color2`, `Color3` are `Blue`, `Red`, `Green`, respectively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arguments for `ColorFunction` in `ParametricPlot3D` are (from the docs):

> ParametricPlot3D      `x, y, z, u` or `x, y, z, u, v`

so you need `#4`, which is `t`.

As for the `ColorFunctionScaling`, I suggest you to read the docs and experiment a little. But just as a hint, you may eliminate both the `ColorFunction -> False` option **AND** the `Rescale` thing in your `CouleurLigne` definition to get the same result :)

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t], Cos[t], t}, {t, Tmin, Tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness@2, 
 ColorFunction -> (CouleurLigne[#4] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer.  But why the ColorFunctionScaling -> False option ?  And why #4 ?