# Adding a fading color to multiple lines in 3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color, parametric-functions

I would like to add a fading color to all the 3D lines I'm drawing with the code below, but I'm having difficulties with implementing the idea.  The curves are starting on a unit sphere, and extend in both directions :  to a central sphere of radius **omega** < 1, and to the exterior of the circle.  The curves should be dark blue on the surface of the sphere, and gently fade away, at a great distance from the sphere, instead of a simple cut.

So here's the code :

```
alpha=40Pi/180;

omega=2Pi (10000)/(299792458*0.001);

Mu0={Sin[alpha],0,Cos[alpha]};

r[x_,y_,z_]:=Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]

Bdipolaire[x_,y_,z_]:=3(Mu0.{x,y,z}){x,y,z}/r[x,y,z]^5-Mu0/r[x,y,z]^3

NormeB[x_,y_,z_]:=Sqrt[Bdipolaire[x,y,z].Bdipolaire[x,y,z]]

Bx[x_,y_,z_]:={1,0,0}.Bdipolaire[x,y,z]
By[x_,y_,z_]:={0,1,0}.Bdipolaire[x,y,z]
Bz[x_,y_,z_]:={0,0,1}.Bdipolaire[x,y,z]

Angles:=
  {0.1972815, 0.1988315,0.2014215,0.2049765,0.2090015,0.2127115,0.2151015,
   0.2151015,0.2116515,0.2031515,0.1692915,0.1687315,0.1705015,0.1723815,
   0.1742015,0.1759465,0.1776115,0.1792415,0.1808415,0.1824015,0.1839215,
   0.1854085,0.1868585,0.1882765,0.1897015,0.1911415,0.1926035,0.1940415,
   0.1953345,0.1963365}

NCourbes:=Length[Angles]

theta[n_]:= Angles[[n]]

phi[n_]:=(n-1)2Pi/NCourbes

CourbeMagnetique[n_]:=NDSolve[{
    x'[s]==Bx[x[s],y[s],z[s]]/NormeB[x[s],y[s],z[s]],
    y'[s]==By[x[s],y[s],z[s]]/NormeB[x[s],y[s],z[s]],
    z'[s]==Bz[x[s],y[s],z[s]]/NormeB[x[s],y[s],z[s]],

    x[0]==(Sin[theta[n]]Cos[phi[n]]Cos[alpha]+Cos[theta[n]]Sin[alpha]),
    y[0]==Sin[theta[n]]Sin[phi[n]],
    z[0]==(Cos[theta[n]]Cos[alpha]-Sin[theta[n]]Cos[phi[n]]Sin[alpha])
    }, 
    {x,y,z}, {s,-10,10},
    Method->Automatic,MaxSteps->10000000,
    StoppingTest->(Sqrt[x[s]^2+y[s]^2+z[s]^2]<omega)]

Do[CourbeMagnetique[n],{n,1,NCourbes}]

Smin[n_]:=(x/.CourbeMagnetique[n])[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
Smax[n_]:=(x/.CourbeMagnetique[n])[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]]

GraphicSize:=1.5

GrapheMagnetique[n_]:=
  ParametricPlot3D[
    Evaluate[{x[s],y[s],z[s]}/.CourbeMagnetique[n]],
    {s,Smin[n],Smax[n]},
    PlotStyle->{Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1]],Blue},
    MaxRecursion->7,PerformanceGoal->"Quality"]

CercleLumiere:=
   ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[p],Sin[p],0},{p,0,2Pi},
     PlotStyle->{Directive[Thick,RGBColor[0.40,0.70,0.40]]},
     PerformanceGoal->"Quality"]

AxesCartesiens=
  {Line[GraphicSize {{-1,0,0},{1,0,0}}],
   Line[GraphicSize {{0,-1,0},{0,1,0}}],
   Line[GraphicSize {{0,0,-1},{0,0,1}}]};

AxeMagnetique=
   Line[(2/3){{-Sin[alpha],0,-Cos[alpha]},{Sin[alpha],0,Cos[alpha]}}];

AxeRotation=Line[(1/3){{0,0,-1},{0,0,1}}];

AxesReference:=
  Graphics3D[{
    {Thin,GrayLevel[0.7],Dashed,AxesCartesiens},
    {Thick,Blue,AxeMagnetique},
    {Thick,RGBColor[0.40,0.70,0.40],AxeRotation}}]

Pulsar:=Graphics3D[Sphere[{0,0,0}, omega]]

Graphique=
  Show[
    Table[GrapheMagnetique[n],{n,1,NCourbes}],CercleLumiere,AxesReference,Pulsar,
    PlotRange->{
      {-GraphicSize,GraphicSize},
      {-GraphicSize,GraphicSize},
      {-GraphicSize,GraphicSize}},
    Boxed->False,Axes->False,Lighting->"Neutral",
    SphericalRegion->True,ViewPoint->{0,0,1}]
```

Here's a picture to show what the code above is currently doing

[image: my picture]

I was thinking about adding a shade like the one below (colors to be edited afterward), to be used instead of the current **Blue** directive, but I don't know how to add it (because of the "s" and "n" variables) :

```
Couleur1 = RGBColor[0,0,1];
Couleur2 = RGBColor[1,0,0];
Couleur3 = RGBColor[0,1,0];

CouleurLigne[s_, n_] := Blend[{Couleur1,Couleur2,Couleur3},  Rescale[s, {Smin[n], Smax[n]}]]
```

So what should be the simplest way of replacing the **Blue** directive to the shade defined above ?  Take note that I'm using **Mathematica 7.0**.

**EDIT :**  I was playing with the answer to a question I asked there : [Colors on a 3D curve not working](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89777/colors-on-a-3d-curve-not-working?rq=1), but the "n" variable is giving me an headache !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) what you want?  (The input is automatically rescaled from 0 to 1, so `Rescale` is unnecessary; see also [`ColorFunctionScaling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html).)

```
GrapheMagnetique[n_] := 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[{x[s], y[s], z[s]} /. CourbeMagnetique[n]], {s, Smin[n], 
   Smax[n]}, PlotStyle -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1]](*,Blue*)}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Couleur1, Couleur2, Couleur3}, #4] &), 
  MaxRecursion -> 7, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I changed your `PlotRange` to `PlotRange -> All` show the color gradient.  The one specified in the OP's code is too small to show the color change.

Comment: Hmmm, it's crashing Mathematica 7.0.  I think it's related to the rescale thing.

Comment: @Cham I don't have V7 to test. It seems like it still works the same (http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html).  In V10, with your original `Rescale` code, it runs for a very long time (I didn't wait long enough to see if it would finish).  But the code above runs in a few seconds.  Sorry, I can't really think of what to try.

Comment: The problem is to take care of the "n" variable.  Without it (i.e. your suggestion) gives a weird output (if Mathematica doesn't crash) ;  the lines are "blinking" while I move around the 3D graphics, and the colors are changing from black to color shades in a weird way.  It feels wrong.  I'm pretty sure it's related to the Rescale option.

Comment: @Cham I don't think I understand what you want with `n`.  These options  give me the same plot: `ColorFunction -> CouleurLigne[#4, n] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False`.  The only use of `n` in `CouleurLigne` is to scale the parameter `s` from 0 to 1 over the domain, which is exactly what the default does (in my answer).  -- The blinking sounds weird.  I tend to associate it with a memory leak leading to an imminent crash.  I get no such behavior.

Comment: The "n" variable allows to define a different color shade for each curve.  The blinking colors may be some weakness of Mathematica 7.0 ?  It's the first time I'm running into a crashing bug with this version.

Comment: Hmm, this is funny.  I just changed the PlotRange to PlotRange -> All, like you, and now the output is perfect.

Comment: @Cham OK, then.  Glad it works.  Unless you want to restrict the plot range.

Comment: But then, why the restricted PlotRange gives a problem ?  it's not even related to the colors !  This is weird.

Comment: @Cham  I no longer know much about V7.  As I said, I tend to associate what you're seeing with crashes. And it *might* have to do with colors in the graphics. A bug in the internal code for rotating figures. I don't see how would one know for sure.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I still have another question, though, about reversing the shades since the field lines are going in two opposite directions from the starting point.  I'll see if I can get it myself before.